# HTML form export to Word document

Tags: php, html, web

Firstly i'm not web developer so be easy on me :)

What i'm looking to do is have a user fill out a normal html form and store it in a word document. Here's the form:

```
    <form action="test2.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And here is test2.php:

```
<?php
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename=SaveAsWordDoc.doc");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">
<title>Saves as a Word Doc</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Header</h1>
  This text can be seen in word
<ul>
<li>List 1</li>
<li>List 2</li>
</ul>
</body>
</htm>
<html>
 <body>

 Hello <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>!<br>
 Your mail is <?php echo $_POST["mail"]; ?>.

 </body>
 </html>
```

I'm not massively familiar with PHP so any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What you're creating **is not a Word document**, it's an HTML document with Word extension (.doc) then your headers are wrong. This may work (or not) but for sure it's not a good practice (and an antivirus, if not Word itself) may complain. You have to **create a Word document from scratch** (for example using Open XML SDK - but it's for .NET, not PHP - if you can target .DOCX) or (if you want to keep HTML source) you can use an empty DOCX template and then **embed an HTML document** inside a DOCX document.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What would be the best way for me to complete this task? Webserver is running on centos, just need a form i can fill out and put into a document even a PDF.

Comment: If you do not have any restriction about document format...what's wrong with an HTML document? It's downloadable and it can be even open in the browser itself...

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just use DOMPDF. Or maybe use openoffice CLI to generate doc from HTML.
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf